# Arithmetic Progression/Sequence | Does it include terms prior to the initial term?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions, arithmetic-functions

I’m trying to find the right term to describe points along a linear equation f(x) = mx + b, but where the domain is restricted to the set of integers. EDIT: Also the slope and y-intercept are integers.

Off hand, an Arithmetic Progression/Sequence appears to fit the bill - except for the notion of an initial term. As the initial term, does that mean the sequence does not contain any terms prior to this along the same linear equation? Or am I overthinking it?

Comment: I think "Arithmetic Progression" is fine.  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) defines it as "An arithmetic progression or arithmetic sequence (AP) is a sequence of numbers such that the difference from any succeeding term to its preceding term remains constant throughout the sequence. " which your sequence satisfies.

Comment: Well, to be fair:  that article also then speaks of an "initial term", so perhaps the use of the term is a bit careless.

Comment: @lulu yea, that’s what was confusing me, haha. So I’m a bit iffy about using it atm

Comment: So, in practice, I'd give the exact definition of the set I had in mind (as you did in your post) and, if I used the term, I'd add a note saying that the sequence was intended to be infinite on both sides, just to avoid ambiguity.  But don't get hung up on semantics, lots of mathematical terms are used with some degree of ambiguity.  "Natural number" doesn't even have a universally agreed upon definition.

Comment: Good call  Thanks!